# Cant get radio button value to post in php

Tags: php, post, radio-button

I started with the code from simplemodal, and modified to suit my needs. That went amazingly well. The last issue I have is getting some radio buttons to post. I'll skip the code blocks I don't think are necessary and just show what I think is relevant. I've tried literally dozens of attempts of solutions from php.net, but nothing seems to work.

HTML

```
<label for='PayPlatform'>Are you willing to pay for a trading platform?</label>
<input type='radio' name='PayPlatform' value='Yes' tabindex='1001' />Yes
<input type='radio' name='PayPlatform' value='No' tabindex='1002' />No
```

Here's where I can't get the value and my attempt there are two attempts in the codeblock below, they were of course not attempted at the same time.

```
else if ($action == "send") {
// other elements form values are retrieved fine, just not the below
$PayPlatform = isset($_POST['PayPlatform']) ? ' checked="checked"' : "";
    //the ternary above just submits 'checked="checked" no matter which radio is checked
    //another attempt
    $PayPlatform = isset($_POST["PayPlatform"]);
    //this just submits "1" weather yes or no is checked
$token = isset($_POST["token"]) ? $_POST["token"] : "";

// make sure the token matches
if ($token === smcf_token($to)) {
    smcf_send($name, $email, $subject, $phone, $message, $PayPlatform);
    echo "Your message was successfully sent, you can close this window";
}
else {
    echo "Unfortunately, your message could not be verified.";
}
}
```

Comment: var_dump($_POST) is your friend

Comment: @sdjuan - I did dump the $_POST, it shows "Yes" for each value that I check yes, but I can't get it to submit yes...see below

Comment: Can you post your var_dump? Maybe that would help with this issue. Eh, nevermind I think Corbin is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$p = (isset($_POST['PayPlatform']) && $_POST['PayPlatform'] == 'Yes');
```

Boolean true if the yes radio is checked, and false otherwise.

Assume you have the following:

```
$a = 'Yes';
isset($a); //true
$b = 'No';
isset($b); //true
```

Strings are considered set, and as PsyCoder said, you'll receive the *value* values, not Booleans.

Also, on a different (chastise-y) note, this question could have been entirely avoided with a bit of better debugging.  The first thing I would have done would have been to var_dump($_POST) and see what the value was.  You'd have then seen that $_POST['PayPlatform'] was always Yes or No, and you'd have potentially realized that isset is always true on strings.

Comment: OK using above I get "1" if they check yes, "2" if they check no. Which to me is acceptable. Unfortunately the person who is receiving this is an idiot and wants to see "Yes" or "No" how would you go about that? I want to get the actual value of the input they select

Comment: Then erm.... use $_POST['PayPlatform']???  (Though I would check to make sure it's set and that it's one of the valid options.)

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign, You should get 'Yes' or 'No'. I'm not sure why you are getting 1 and especially 2 given the information above.

Comment: I'm sorry Corbin. I'm learning. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: did this "var_dump($PayPlatform)" and I get bool(true) if yes ischecked, and bool(false) if No is checked. However, the email with the form data displays a "1" if true and nothing if blank.

Comment: That's because $PayPlatform in my example is a boolean, not a string.  'Yes' and 'No' are fine in English conversation, but I prefer true and false in the realm of logic.  If you want to print yes or not based on it, just do echo ($PayPlatform ? 'Yes' : 'No');

Comment: I apologize for being so obtuse here, pls understand I'm learning. I do indeed want it to print yes or no based on which box was checked. I'm not sure how to use "echo ($PayPlatform ? 'Yes' : 'No'); in the code I posted at the top. Simply pasting it in is not allowing the script to run

Comment: This helped me find the way to do it myself. $PayPlatform = ($_POST["PayPlatform"]) ? "Pay for Platform: Yes":"Pay for Platform: No"; I guess the old Marine in me responds better to chastising. Thanks Corbin!

Comment: No problem.  I'm assuming though that you've changed the value="" to 0 and 1 or something?  Since Yes and No will both evaluate to true, that ternary will always result in the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You wont get value as checked or unchecked... rather you'll receive the  `value='No'` or `value='No'` parameter value specified in your html...

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST["PayPlatform"] == "Yes") {
    $PayPlatform = true;
}
```

Keeping it simple :)

Comment: Keeping it simple?  Then why in the world is strip_tags there?!

Comment: Coding habit, i'll never trust user submitted content :) Maybe not needed in this case, but i put it always in examples :)

Comment: It's 100% pointless though.  In fact, I would consider it wrong.  <p>Yes</p> should not == 'Yes' but in your example it will.  If someone has been tampering with my form values, I like to know it, not to ignore it :).  HTML escaping (or removal) only makes sense in the context of HTML.  When you're comparing for equality, it's no longer 'html' unless the user is actaully supposed to be submitting HTML.  htmlspecialentities'ing html being printed is essential, but this seems like you've taken that a bit too far.

Comment: Point taken :) Thanks for this usefull comment.